# notification for email to case using salesforce for outlook

Tags: case, salesforce-for-outlook, email2case

When we're adding case to salesforce using outlook tool and it's creating case perfectly to the queue but it is not giving/prompting any email notification when case is being added using same configuration.

Here's some points I've figured out:

> - Email notification setting is set to send email when it hits assignment rule.
> - Outlook configuration doesn't allow to save settings without assigning user/queue as case owner.
> - Regardless of case record type, if case owner is already assigned, it won't assign case owner again.

Is there any work around to notify queue on case arrival using salesforce for outlook configuration without using custom trigger?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't help much, but on the Case Page Layout you can add the (via Layout Properties) the 2 checkboxes that are Run Assignment Rules and Notify Owner. So the user adds the case via Outlook and THEN has to navigate to the case and check these checkboxes to "re-assign" the case (owner may not change, but assignment rules should run).

It's extra work for your users, but it should work.

Note that if you use a trigger you'll have to call an @future method because triggers are called before assignment rules and don't cause them to be fired. So you'll call an at @future method which has the Case Id passed to, using that you then use database.update(cases you've queried from case Id(s), dmlOptions) where the dmlOptions indicate to fire assignment rules and notify users.

Link to info on dmlOptions https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm

Comment: We had considered this before and this checkbox **Assign using active assignment rules** was marked as default but it was reassigning case every time user edit any data in case. Also checkbox creation you suggested would prompt notification only if user manually check and edit data in salesforce. I want to prompt notification on case arrival from outlook without user touching records in salesforce, we can create workflow rule for this but it would send two notifications when case will actually arrive directly from service address using email to case functionality.

Comment: Also I was looking for some standard resolution for this, rather than going for trigger or workflow rules, If I have to go for workflow then I'll have to disable email functionality in assignment rules and will have to create different workflows with different email notifications for different queues, which is currently being solved directly by assignment rules.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this without a user making an extra click or some apex code. What you need is SFO to set the header when calling the API to insert the Case where the header has use default assignment rule = true and notify user = true. Here is the idea you can vote up https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dgs5AAC

Comment: Vote done, but I'm pretty sure this is not gonna be resolved from salesforce side as it's having too less votes with around just 120 Points, we need almost like 5-7K for them to notice. That's sad part of salesforce success community.